# dbup does not create schemaversions table automatically

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, mariadb, dbup

I installed the latest DbUp version 4.4.0 from nuget and followed the steps described in the docs

https://dbup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I'm using a MySQL database and created a new .NET Core console project.

- There is no database present yet. I deleted it
- I installed the dbup and dbup-mysql package
- I copied the sample code from the docs and modified it a little bit

  ```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=my_database;Uid=root;Pwd=admin;";

        EnsureDatabase.For.MySqlDatabase(connectionString);

        var upgrader = DeployChanges.To
                .MySqlDatabase(connectionString)
                .WithScriptsEmbeddedInAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                .Build();

        var result = upgrader.PerformUpgrade();

        if (!result.Successful)
        {
            throw result.Error;
        }
    }
  ```
- I created a new .sql file within that project and called it *1595961596-initial_script.sql* and defined it as an **embedded resource**

.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `my_database`;
CREATE DATABASE `my_database`;
```

- When running the project `result.Successful` returns false and throws this error

> Table 'my_database.schemaversions' doesn't exist

I thought that it would generate the `schemaversions` table automatically? Does someone know how to fix it?

---

If it helps:
I'm using Linux with MariaDb. I also tried to create that table on my own with

https://dbup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more-info/journaling/

```
.JournalToSqlTable("my_database", "schemaversions")
```

but then I get this error

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
> version for the right syntax to use near
> '[my_database].[schemaversions] (
> [Id] int identity(1,1) not null constraint' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I came here because I saw this error... except in my case, it appears to be related to this old bug somehow: https://github.com/DbUp/DbUp/issues/188 . Another schema already had a `schemaversions` table.